# Open cones in Macaulay2

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, geometric-inequalities, macaulay2

I need to create some polyhedral cones and form their intersections.  Macaulay2 looks like a great tool for this, and so I set up M2 on a Linux box.  I've been able to make the cones and form intersections as desired, but I am hitting a snag.  It appears that Macaulay2 defines a cone so that it contains its boundary, but I need to work with cones that do not contain their boundaries.  Any ideas for how I should deal with this?